# Help with Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, Here is my problem:

I have this function in a third party javascript library defined as `RedirectLink(a,b,c,d,e)` where a,b,c,d,e are strings.

I also have a link in my webSite which is again autogenerated (And I can't change it)

```
<a href="javascript: RedirectLink("1", "2", "3" ,"4" ,"5")" id="mylink" >
```

What I need to do is, read this anchor's (mylink) href and I need to call RedirectLink function such as `javascript: RedirectLink("1", "2", "3" + param, "4" , "5")`. where `param` will come from query string.

The first part is easy, reading the href but how to alter the third parameter ?

Comment: This query value is the query string of the current URL?

Comment: yes, basically I need to append something to third argument coming from query string. Data types can be ignored.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then why are you using javascript: RedirectLink("1", "2", "3" + param, "4" , "5") in your html? jQuery has specific event handlers that allow you to properly separate your concerns. What you have written is very poor practice.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I am just constructing the link which I will assign to anchor. How else can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mhm... You can make an hack like this:

via javascript you can change href from `javascript: RedirectLink(1,2,3,4,5)` to `javascript: MyRedirectLink(1,2,3,4,5)`, then define `MyRedirectLink`:

```
var param = 'xxx';
function MyRedirectLink(a, b, c, d, e) {
    RedirectLink(a, b, c + param, d, e)
}
```

Not elegant but it should work (if `param` can be computed outside your function).

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
$(function() {

    var $mylink = $('#mylink');
    var href = $mylink.attr('href');

    // getting the array of arguments
    var args = href.substr( href.indexOf('(') + 1 );
    args = args.slice(0, args.length - 1);
    args = args.split(',');

    // getting the string value for each array item
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        args[i] = $.trim(args[i]);
        args[i] = args[i].slice(1, args[i].length - 1);
    }

    // augmenting the third argument
    args[2] += window.location.href;

    $mylink.attr('href', '#').click(function() {
        RedirectLink(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, This looks like a lot of parsing. Let me try this too.